# Visual Studio Add-In - adding a context menu item to solution-explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm developing my first add-in for Visual studio and we need to *add a context menu item to the solution explorer, that shows up for particular file types only (in our case - ".resx").*

I've been googling for 2 days now, unable to find any tutorials or code-samples... Only very basic things like adding a menu-item to the VS "tools" menu etc.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you need to create a dynamically visible command that you will make visible only when the selected node in the Solution Explorer is .resx file and then add the command as a child of the Solution Explorer context menu (you would need GUID:ID pair of the latter).

Here is a good article showing how to do that: http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2008/03/22/dynamic-menu-commands-in-visual-studio-packages-part-2/

Comment: A working one (except images): http://davedewinter.com/2008/03/22/dynamic-menu-commands-in-visual-studio-packages-part-2/

Comment: Oleg, @Alex 's problem is why you must [quote the most relevant part of an important link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)! (also note the new link went down too)