# VS2010 add-in custom menu item in files of Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, vsx

I need to create a custom menu item for Visual Studio 2010 Add-in in C#, but I have had no luck in finding a solution for my needs.

I am aware that there was a similar post ([Visual Studio Add-In - adding a context menu item to solution-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486818/visual-studio-add-in-adding-a-context-menu-item-to-solution-explorer)), but it did not help, as the blog follows the process through the integration package, and the video is done through VB. I had attempted to convert the VB syntax to the C# syntax, but about half way through the video, the Add-in methods has significantly changed from 2005 to 2010, as some of the methods have removed or changed.

Is there any good tutorials on making a custom menu item on the Solution Explorer in the lastest Visual Studio in C#, and is there a good website that could be used as a reference for looking over the VS add-in API? I've used Microsoft's main website, however it is confusing and wordy, which is difficult to understand and find the methods, properties, or commands that I am looking for.

Any help would be appreicated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

what are you writing? a number of cool add-ons already exist that might solve your problem..

such as [vs 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about it but you might want to check out [MME MenuManagerTemplate](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7c965998-dd09-4246-b31c-dd7042d82c3d) and the sister project on CodePlex [Managed Menu Extensions](http://mme.codeplex.com/)

Looks like the majority of the code is in the project on CodePlex so you could see how that project is implemented.