# Extending VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to extend Visual Studio such that, when someone right clicks on Solution Explorer, context menu should have a new menu item, say "Open custom form", clicking which should open a form (this form would actually accept some settings and modify config file accordingly)

Q1. Please provide on where should I start for such extension. Couldn't find any reference/tutorial link :(
Q2. What technology can be used to make such a form - Winforms/WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Either Windows Forms or WPF should be fine.

- SO: [Visual Studio Add-In - adding a context menu item to solution-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486818/visual-studio-add-in-adding-a-context-menu-item-to-solution-explorer)
- Google Code: [explorer-popup-add-in](http://code.google.com/p/explorer-popup-add-in/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of docs on Visual Studio integration [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166030.aspx)