# Visual Studio AddIn: How do I Add Item Specific Commands to the Solution Explorer Context Menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, visual-studio-addins, solution-explorer

I've spent about 3 days now trying to get this working but to no avail.

I'm fairly new to VS.NET extensibility and I find it hard to debug my problems.

I've already tried the code here presented: [Visual Studio Add-In - adding a context menu item to solution-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486818/visual-studio-add-in-adding-a-context-menu-item-to-solution-explorer)

Couldnt make it work. Debugged it and no exception is being thrown. Plus I'd rather use an AddIn instead of a Package.

Anyone knows:

- How to obtain a list of all context menus in the solution explorer?
- How to add custom command groups to a context menu?
- How to add a custom command to one custom command group of a context menu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So - are you doing a VSX package or Add-In?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2011/MZ2011015.aspx) shows how to create and display a context menu with the same look and feel than the ones of Visual Studio to be used in your own add-in user-interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool that I recommend based on having used it: http://vssdkassist.codeplex.com/. It is aimed at Visual studio packages as oposed to addins, but the method calls are similar between addins and vspackages. I would recommend setting up a vspackage project, use vssdkassist to do that, and use it to create your context menu. I would then recommend researching into the method calls etc that vssdkassist sets up for you.